# Facebook ThumbnailCreation

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I am wishing to know, how to update a thumbnail for facebook, when the
Facebook Debugger tool will not recognize the new updated thumbnail

the new thumbnail is uploaded on to the server over the old one, and then i
have used the facebook debug page

how can i make fb debug realize there is a new thumb(nail ).jpg on the
server?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is the linter tool to force it to refresh faster than the normal 24 hours.

If the linter tool does not recognize the new thumbnail, make sure it is compliant with the height and width requirements (50x50).  Also be sure the width to height ratio is also not too high (ratio<3.0).

For additional requirements, please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/